# How to skip counting same value set in 2 columns that appears in another 2 columns set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day, I need some help on how to form an Excel formula to count distinct for values in 2 columns with other columns:

[image: excel example]

I want to count a number of subjects assigned to "ummu", but that same subject name appears again shouldn't be count. In this example, the count will return 4. How can I achieve this using excel formula?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to count distinct records assigned to 'Ummu' from [this range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUT0C.png) built on the source range?

Comment: Correct @omegastripes. There subject may appear in other course, but if the name of the subject and the person in-charge is the same, it should not count. :)

Comment: You can do that manually using Excel ["Remove Duplicates" tool on "Data" ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUN85.png) on [that range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUT0C.png), and then by filtering.

Comment: @omegastripes - but i want have a count for all the person, how many subjects has been assigned to them. Its not that i want to remove the duplicate. Any formula like countif can do this?

Comment: Initially, you asked not for all persons but only one. Please edit the question then, change the title, change the source range to the relevant which should look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUT0C.png), and expected output, where all persons exist. Otherwise, the question and the comments might confuse others.

Comment: I manage to solve this using the following formula : =SUMPRODUCT((($C$2:$C$354=F10))/COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$354,$C$2:$C$354&"",$B$2:$B$354,$B$2:$B$354&""))

Thanks for your time @omegastripes. Appreciate it